'ML' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I'm currently writing assembly language using Irvine32. I want to add a new procedure to irvine32.lib by myself. However, when I execute makeLib.bat, I encounter the following error:
"'ML' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
How can I solve this?
I want to successfully execute makeLib.bat and generate files such as lib.exe, link.exe, ml.exe, mspdb120.dll. However, when I try to run makeLib.bat, I encounter errors. How can I resolve this issue and generate these files?

https://github.com/Eazybright/Irvine32/blob/master/Lib32/Irvine32_Library/makeLib.bat says to run it from the Visual Studio command prompt.  Are you doing that?

When I run makeLib.bat, I encounter the following error: "tbbmalloc.dll not found." How can I resolve this issue?
